# How to automate running of Jupyter Notebook cells periodically

Tags: python, sql-server, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, plotly

I want to integrate my jupyter notebook with my website, where I have written the code to fetch real-time data from `MySQL` server and do real-time visualisation using `plotly`. But every time I'm having to run all the cells of my Kernel. Is there a way I can automate the running of the Jupyter notebook cells periodically say everyday 1 hour?

Comment: So you are **NOT** using sql server? Then why tag it?

Comment: Hi, , I, am using SQL server of my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to

- [Setup](https://awc.com.my/uploadnew/5ffbd639c5e6eccea359cb1453a02bed_Setting%20Up%20Cron%20Job%20Using%20crontab.pdf) a cron job with the periodicity you want.
- Use [runipy](https://github.com/paulgb/runipy)
  to run all the cells in the notebook. It has a lot of functionality
  like saving the run as html report. This will particularly be
  useful in your case as you want to visualise plotly plots.

I can provide the commands here, but they are pretty straight forward and can easily be followed from the links.

Comment: So I can directly link it to my website? And like it will run throughout the day on its own,whatever I've coded in it?

Comment: The runipy site notes that it "started before Jupyter's [execute API](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html), which is now the recommended way to run notebooks from the command-line."

Comment: As @fact_finder notes, runipy is now deprecated, and points uses to the execute API of nbconvert.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time
 
# Wait for 3600 seconds
while True:
    time.sleep(3600)
    #YOUR CODE HERE
```

If you want not to wait for the cell in running mode you can run the code above inside a thread

Answer (score 0):

Please setup a function that runs for an interval of 1 hour using the Javascript `setInterval` function. Inside the interval function you can call the `jupyter` object method, to run all cells.

```
%%html
<script>
    // AUTORUN ALL CELLS ON NOTEBOOK-LOAD!
    require(
        ['base/js/namespace', 'jquery'], 
        function(jupyter, $) {
            $(jupyter.events).on("kernel_ready.Kernel", function () {
                setInterval(function(){
                  console.log("Auto-running all cells-below...");
                  jupyter.actions.call('jupyter-notebook:run-all-cells-below');
                  // jupyter.actions.call('jupyter-notebook:save-notebook');
                }, 60000); // 60000 for 1 hour interval gap
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Note: I have added the `setInterval` part of the script by myself, the major code,comes from this [`SO answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984196/ipython-notebook-run-all-cells-on-open)

Comment: `// 60000 for 1 hour interval gap` is not correct, should be `3600000` (60 *  60 * 1000 = hour in milliseconds)