# How to trigger an existing Jupyter Notebook upon data update

Tags: jupyter-notebook

If I have to design a Jupyter notebook (with Python), the notebook will read data for customized transform. The data will get refreshed everyday but time is uncertain.

I wonder how is it possible to trigger the notebook to automatically get executed when there is a data update? I am guessing Airflow might be a feasible solution but I won't consider Airflow at this moment for simplicity reason.

Update:
The suggested post [How to automate running of Jupyter Notebook cells periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692672/how-to-automate-running-of-jupyter-notebook-cells-periodically) in the comment is different. Its "solution" is to run a cron job blindly - definitely not a good solution. I expect some **trigger** that will lead the notebook being executed. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automate running of Jupyter Notebook cells periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692672/how-to-automate-running-of-jupyter-notebook-cells-periodically).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automate running of Jupyter Notebook cells periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692672/how-to-automate-running-of-jupyter-notebook-cells-periodically)

Comment: No, that post is different. And the "solution" is to run a cron job blindly - definitely not a good solution. I expect some trigger that will lead the notebook being executed. Thanks.