# remove non-breaking space from python code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I get an error while trying to import a module:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

> SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

This is because there is a non breaking space at the end of the string:

```
x='from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split '

x[-1:]
```

> '\xa0'

I can replace that space and then copy-paste the code like this:

```
import unicodedata
new_str = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", x)

print (new_str)
```

This new string have no issues:

> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

But I will like to know if ipython notebook has built-in function to correct such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subject discussed on Github page of jupyter-notebook.

***Links*** :

[Strip trailing whitespace](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1455) (Closed)

[Trailing whitespace in editor](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2756) (Open)

[Trailing whitespace in editor](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3904) (Open)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built-in function in iPython. Custom magic commands can be created in iPython using this [guide](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html)

Comment: Is there any way to write a trigger that will run a function when a cell is executed? I do not want to add @cell_magic at the beginning of every cell as suggested. The magic should happen on the fly :)

Comment: You can write a jquery something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38856870/6537262

Comment: That code will autorun all cells on notebook-load. I am trying to autorun on single cell execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
x='from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split '
print(x.strip())
```