# Autorun specific, hidden cells jupyterlab

Tags: ipython, jupyter-lab

I have code cells with ipython widgets, whose input is hidden, and i want them to be running when opening. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984196/jupyter-notebook-run-all-cells-on-open) but it did not work on jupyterlab also after running it manually. Extension i found [here](https://github.com/epi2me-labs/jupyterlab-autorun-cells) is not compatible yet with jupyterlab 3.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter(lab) developers will do their best to prevent you from doing this as it is a security issue. The hidden cells could contain `rm -rf /`, or steal your bitcoin wallet, or anything else. Thus it is not only advised against doing so; any solution that would be posted will likely trigger the Jupyter developers to actively work to block the suggested solution.

I would thus advise to not try to do that.

Comment: is there then an alternative to implement widgets without executing the code?

Comment: If you ask widgets maybe you are trying to do a dashboard-y thing ? Then look at voilà https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila, or pannel https://panel.holoviz.org/; if it's a server you control, then you can have code execution when the page is visited, as the code is not arbitrary and not on user machine. But in general if it's on opening on notebook file, the answer will likely be no, there is no way.